# how can i append to each line in scala and why is it saying unit?

Tags: string, scala

im doing something stupid to try to send html email and not really understanding what im doing but I want to send a multiline string to a function and get the same string back with something appended to each line - what am i doing wrong?

```
def htmlizetext(intext: String)  {
  for(line <- intext.linesWithSeparators) {
    <br>line<br/>
  }
}


def htmlizetext(intext: String): String = {
 for(line <- intext.linesWithSeparators) {
   line + "<br/>"
 }
}
```

Neither of the above work

Comment: Either use `yield` or use `map`.

Comment: so i dont neet to return but sometimes i need to yield

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `yield`, `=` (without `=` the method will still return `Unit`) and some form of concatenation:

```
def htmlizetext(intext: String) = {
  for (line <- intext.linesWithSeparators) yield {
    line + "<br/>
  }
}.mkString
```

or the shorter equivalent:

```
def htmlizetext(intext: String) =
  intext.linesWithSeparators.map(_ + "<br/>").mkString
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at `yield`, that is probably what you are looking for.

```
def htmlizetext(intext: String) = {
  for(line <- intext.linesWithSeparators) yield {
    <br>line<br/>
  }
}
```

You might additionally want to join all the elements from the returning list for returning a single `String` instead of a list of such strings

You are currently not returning a thing from your method as you do not return anything from your `for` statement which is the last method of your statement. Therefore, the Scala compiler infers that you are returning `Unit`.

Answer (score 0):

Because for does't have a return value, unless you use yield...
A better solution would be to "map" your collection as follows:

```
intext.linesWithSeparators.map(line=> s"$line<br/>").mkString("")
```

this will turn your string in the desired format and then join all of them using mkString. If you need it, you can specify a separator instead of empty string